# Strong resolvent convergence and spectral measures

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Suppose $\{A_n\}$ is a sequence of self-adjoint operators in a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, and $A$ is a self-adjoint operator, with $A_n \to A$ in the strong resolvent sense. Denoting by $E_n$ and $E$ the spectral measures of $A_n$ and $A$ respectively, what can be said about the strong limits of $\{E_n(\Omega)\}$, for $\Omega$ a Borel set in $\mathbb R$?

Supposing $\sigma_p(A) = \emptyset$, for every $a,b \in \mathbb R$ it holds
$$ E_n((a,b)) \to E((a,b)) \mbox{  strongly} $$

What can be said in the case of a generic Borel set?

Comment: Does strong convergence mean pointwise convergence on $H$? In analogy with Pormanteau's Theorem I guess that $E_n(B) \to E(B)$ whenever $B$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $E(\partial B) = 0$, and that this assumption on $B$ can not be removed.

Comment: Your guess is my guess as well, but I have not found any proof in the literature